# Python write to multiple files write data to the previous file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have twenty files. I read them one by one and count the items, and I write the answer in another file. If I name each file manually, (e.g. run40.txt), it works well.

But instead I read the file in a loop. It works only for the first file, but for the rest it starts adding the answer of previous files to the current file.

```
#!/usr/bin python
import glob
import sys
from collections import Counter
import time
c=Counter()

for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    print file
    myfile = open(file, "r")

 for line in myfile:
     c.update(line.split())

 for item in c.items():
     outfile= open(file + ".out", 'a+')
     print >> outfile, "{}\t{}".format(*item)
 outfile.close()
 myfile.close()
```

Why did it add the output of the previously closed file to the new file?

Comment: First, you must clear the counter before starting working on the next file. Second, there is no need to open the output file for each item. Open it at the same time with `myfile`.

Comment: @DYZ Thanks alot its done I addd ` c.clear()` after the `print >> outfile, "{}\t{}".format(*item)`. The problem with the counter, need to clear it.